# Не получается оформить кнопку 'submit' в css

Tags: javascript, kohana, css

Доброе всем время.

У меня javascript добавляет строку в таблице, в которой добавляется кнопка (в виде [картинки](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/69mfzb7ki8fbzwv/AABzImrsl3ORgwkuqVgreGQLa?dl=0)):

```
<td><input name='save' type='submit' class='btn_save'></td>
```

Которую я пробую описывать в  css:

```
.btn_save 
   {height: 50px; 
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0; 
    padding:0; 
    border: 0; 
    background: transparent url('save.png') no-repeat center top; 
    text-indent: -1000em; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    cursor: hand; }
```

Сразу скажу, что такое оформление подсмотрел на [сайте](http://lifeexample.ru/css-verstka-sayta/submit-kartinkoy.html).
Но почему-то у меня в разных browsers происходит что-то непонятное с размерами кнопки, (допустим, когда я открыл режим ("opera drgonfly") в opera, я увидел, что это высота первоначальной кнопки "submit" режет изображение, а в dreamweaver – как бы все нормально, но текст кнопки «submit» лежит по вех моего изображения), т.е. во всех browser у меня творится какая-то фигня.

Где тут собака зарыта?

P.S. Если я описываю ее в html, то все нормально:

```
<?=Form::image(
     'submit', 'picture', 
      array('src'  => 'media/Img/save.png',
         'onmouseover'   => 'this.src=\'/media/Img/save_click.png\';',
         'onmouseout'    => 'this.src=\'/media/Img/save.png\';',
      )
)?>
```

Comment: > а в dreamweaver

@Konstantin78, Dreamweaver - не браузер :)

Кроме того, зачем "пихать" форму в таблицу? Почему бы Вам не использовать [inline стиль](http://habrahabr.ru/post/161581/) вёрстки для блочных элементов. Если не ошибаюсь, Вы разрабатываете сервис для ограниченного числа пользователей, поэтому смело используйте [flexbox-ы](https://vimeo.com/67011034).

Как вариант, если нет навыков вёрстки, используйте css фреймворк. К примеру, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: I. Да о Dreamweaver я в курсе, просто там есть режим "Split", который сразу показывает графический результат.
II. <?=Form - просто в kohana так описывается картинка.
III. в одной из колонок  таблицы я редактирую запись, а вдругой колонке, я вывожу кнопку "Сохранить"
IV. о "inline стиль" - я подумаю, спасибо...
V. Так чтоже не правильно с css? Кстати Dreamweaver тоже показывает графический результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> просто там есть режим "Split"

Да, я в курсе. Использовал этот продукт еще когда он принадлежал компании [Macromedia](http://goo.gl/aXco2z)

[[@Konstantin78](/users/19954/konstantin78)](/users/19954/konstantin78), не очень понято, зачем Вы используете отступ `text-indent` (а-ля красная строка). Хотя, наверно, чтобы дефолтный текст убрать. Достаточно для кнопки прописать `value=""`:

```
<input name='save' type='submit' class='btn_save' value="">
```

- [Пример с загрузкой по url](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/qjg60ut8/4/) (могут быть проблемы с 403/404 ошибкой, ибо грузится с dropbox)
- [Пример с data uri (изображение в base64 кодировке)](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/qjg60ut8/2/). Поддержка [браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант подошел, но у меня небольшая неувязочка. В значение 

      value="                  "
Нужно пробелами указать истинную ширину картинки, иначе ширина кнопки схлопывается до приблизительно пол миллиметра (смотрел в "opera" "FireFox"). Может, конечно, с шириной можно как-нибудь по-другому поступить.

Comment: @Konstantin78, явное объявление ширины input-а с картинкой должно быть достаточным.

    .btn_save {
        width: 70px;
    }

В Вашем и моём примере это указано. Странное поведение. Неплохо было бы взглянуть на всю таблицу с формой, либо её часть на http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Я для начала попробывал просто в пустом html прописать тег с кнопкой и  с стилем [html][1]:   
и [картинокой][2]

  [1]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aoiva173jy6o7dw/button.html?dl=0
  [2]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8ajn3oj26g5csn/save.png?dl=0

Comment: И в таблице - все нормально только с 

    value="                  "
Класс!

Comment: @Konstantin78, пропишите `width: 70px;`. В [вашем пример](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aoiva173jy6o7dw/button.html?dl=0) ширина не указана.

    <input name='save' type='submit' class='btn_save' value="">
    
    .btn_save {
        height: 25px; 
        width: 70px;
        border: 0; 
        background: url(http://i.imgur.com/QZ5zi4K.png); 
        cursor: pointer; 
    }

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/qjg60ut8/5/).

Comment: @romeo Если Вам не трудно скачать мой html, то там есть параметр "width: 70px";  
**Моя ошибка** заключалась в неправильном оформлении комментария после строки "height: 25px;" и т.д. Я его, по незнанию поставил после (как в javascript)  
    
     "//", 

а нужно заключать в     

    "/* ... */"

Извеняюсь... В моем самом первом примере, я их убрал, хотя не нужно было этого делать (быстрее бы нашли ошибку)

Answer (score 1):

Применяйте стиль не к классу, а к элементу:

```
[css]

input[type=submit] {
    •••
}

[/css]
```

или конкретизируйте (если еще будут сабмиты с другими стилями):

```
[css]

input[type=submit].btn_save {
    •••
}

[/css]
```